# Typescript - Generic constraint to pass zod schema result into function as argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, zod

I am trying to build a custom controller function to reduce the bloat of my application. Wrapping try-catch, parsing a zod schema, and then merging the request zod schema into single object exists in all of the handler functions, hence I wanted to have a wrapper to handle these for each request. But I want to ensure type safety while doing so. Here is the function I have so far:

```
function controller<
  T extends B & Q & P,
  B extends Record<string, any>,
  Q extends Record<string, any>,
  P extends Record<string, any>
>(handlerFn: (args: T) => Promise<any>, zodSchema: { parse: (data: unknown) => { body: B; query: Q; params: P } }) {
  return async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {
    try {
      const r = zodSchema.parse(req);
      const args = { ...r.body, ...r.params, ...r.query };
      await handlerFn(args);
    } catch (e) {
      next(e);
    }
  };
}
```

It takes a `handlerFn`, which is the core function, which takes a parameter T. It takes a `zodSchema` as its second parameter, in which after parsing should validate and return body, query, and params fields since we are going to validate the Request object. I want the input of the `handlerFn` to be merged body, query, and params.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Argument of type 'B & P & Q' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
  'B & P & Q' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Record<string, any>'.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't use `T`, since `T extends B & Q & P` is not the same as `T = B & Q & P` and `T` may have some other fields. Instead, type the func as follows:`handlerFn: (args: B & Q & P) => Promise<any>`

Comment: Awesome, it works @wonderflame! Add an answer and I will upvote right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `T extends B & Q & P` is not the same as `T = B & Q & P`, and `T` may have some other fields; thus, `B & Q & P` won't be considered as `T`.  Instead of using `T` just use `B & Q & P` directly on the `handlerFn`:

```
function controller<
  B extends Record<string, any>,
  Q extends Record<string, any>,
  P extends Record<string, any>
>(
  handlerFn: (args: B & Q & P) => Promise<any>,
  zodSchema: { parse: (data: unknown) => { body: B; query: Q; params: P } }
) {
  return async (req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
    try {
      const r = zodSchema.parse(req);
      const args = { ...r.body, ...r.params, ...r.query };
      await handlerFn(args);
    } catch (e) {
      next(e);
    }
  };
}
```